# Google Maps Api v3 DrawingManager - Start drawing without using drawingControl

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm building a geofencing api with google maps api v3. I started from MapToolbar code :
http://nettique.free.fr/gmap/toolbar.html

I like it because it's really easy to customize like changing the icons and all the way the functions are called. I only use the polygon tool and I don't like the fact that you can't make convex angle when you add a point (only when you edit it after).

You can do it if you use drawingManager tools because the polygon is created only after you have completed the drawing :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools

But I don't like the default icons and I think the way the functions are called is not really user friendly. The thing is that I'm not able to call the functions by myself.

So, I'm looking for a way to start drawing without using the default drawing control as simple as calling the right function but I can't find it! Or maybe I can create polygons the same way without using drawingManager at all. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

I found it! If you want to hide the control menu, use `drawingControl: false` and if you want to change the drawing mode, use `setDrawingMode()` as explained here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DrawingManager

So, this is the new code starting in polygon drawing mode:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Drawing tools</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=drawing"></script>
    <script>

// ColorLuminance() is a little extra to have your strokeColor
// darker than your fillColor

function ColorLuminance(hex, lum) {

    // validate hex string
    hex = String(hex).replace(/[^0-9a-f]/gi, '');
    if (hex.length < 6) {
        hex = hex[0]+hex[0]+hex[1]+hex[1]+hex[2]+hex[2];
    }
    lum = lum || 0;

    // convert to decimal and change luminosity
    var rgb = "#", c, i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        c = parseInt(hex.substr(i*2,2), 16);
        c = Math.round(Math.min(Math.max(0, c + (c * lum)), 255)).toString(16);
        rgb += ("00"+c).substr(c.length);
    }

    return rgb;
}

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    zoom: 8
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
    drawingControl: false,
    polygonOptions: {
      strokeWeight: 2,
      strokeColor: ColorLuminance("#FF0000", -0.6),
      strokeOpacity: 0.9,
      fillColor: "#FF0000",
      fillOpacity: 0.3
    }
  });
  drawingManager.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```